# Python Matlab file: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 44: invalid start byte

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am trying to read a matlab file with SCIPY.IO library. And i am recieving the following error

Drives = sio.loadmat('Data/Drives.mat')

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Mic
rosoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 76, in
exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\nasir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EnergyInformatics\E
nergyInformatics\main.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\nasir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EnergyInformatics\E
nergyInformatics\main.py", line 44, in main
    simulation = SetupSimulation(server_sock=None,NUMBER_OF_PEVS=item[0],Grid_Fa
ctor=item[1],SOLAR_FACTOR=5,CHARGE_AT="HOME",ONE_PARKING_PERIOD=True,PARAM_FILEN
AME=None)
  File "C:\Users\nasir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EnergyInformatics\E
nergyInformatics\SetupSimulation.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.GenerateVehicles()
  File "C:\Users\nasir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EnergyInformatics\E
nergyInformatics\SetupSimulation.py", line 99, in GenerateVehicles
    drivingProfiles, consumptionProfiles = self.Create_Driving_Profiles(self.NUM
BER_OF_PEVS, TIMESTEPS_DRIVING, STEPSIZE, DAY_TYPE, SEASON)
  File "C:\Users\nasir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EnergyInformatics\E
nergyInformatics\SetupSimulation.py", line 130, in Create_Driving_Profiles
    muenchenDrives = sio.loadmat('Data/muenchenDrives.mat')
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 175, in load
mat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 292, in get
_variables
    res = self.read_var_array(hdr, process)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 255, in rea
d_var_array
    return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 624, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.arra
y_from_header (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:5401)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 671, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.arra
y_from_header (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:5062)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 900, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read
_struct (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:7576)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 622, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read
_mi_matrix (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:4662)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 669, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.arra
y_from_header (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:5040)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 822, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read
_cells (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:6748)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 622, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read
_mi_matrix (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:4662)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 665, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.arra
y_from_header (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:4979)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 802, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read
_char (scipy\io\matlab\mio5_utils.c:6450)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 44: invalid
 start byte
```

I have tried the codecs library too but it did not work. any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: What's the version of the .mat file?

Comment: I think i have solved the problem. I just opened the file in matlab and saved it again using matlab SAVE(). It solved the issue. Thanks for your help